# how to import graphql schema to graphene-python program?

Tags: python, graphql

How do I import an existing graphql schema (example below) into a graphene program instead of defining classes in python to create the schema?

```
type Hello {
   name: String
}
type Query {
  hello: Hello!
}

schema {
  query: Query
}
```

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45915822/how-to-add-resolvers-root-value-to-a-graphql-schema-in-python-graphql-core

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Graphene needs the class definitions to act upon them, especially your resolver implementations.

There is no codegen for graphql to python classes at this moment.